# gentoo bonded nics dropping packets

Tags: linux, gentoo

I have two nics bonded in gentoo, eth2 and eth3 to bond0. eth2 is connected to a different switches than eth3 for redundancy with eth2 in standby and eth3 in active mode. eth3 is running fine with no drops but eth2 is dropping packets constantly.I swapped cables and checked the switch ports which show no errors. I did a TCPDUMP on eth2 and all I saw was arp requests.

> eth2: flags=6211  mtu 1500
>           ether 90:b1:1c:19:59:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 32664867  bytes 2090551811 (1.9 GiB)
>           RX errors 0  **dropped 32664913**  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>           device interrupt 36  memory 0xd7000000-d77fffff
>
> eth3: flags=6211  mtu 1500
>           ether 90:b1:1c:19:59:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>           RX packets 3186342439  bytes 683402238345 (636.4 GiB)
>           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>           TX packets 2465388994  bytes 575317691871 (535.8 GiB)
>           TX errors 0  **dropped 0** overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>           device interrupt 37  memory 0xd8000000-d87fffff
>
> Kernel
>   Linux 3.7.9-gentoo
>
> ### net config

config_eth0="null"
    config_eth1="null"

```
config_eth2="null"
config_eth3="null"
slaves_bond0="eth2 eth3"
config_bond0="64.241.127.5/27"
routes_bond0="default via 64.241.127.1"
```

> ### ethtool output

```
 Settings for eth2:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 18
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)

    Link detected: yes

Settings for eth3:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 19
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)

    Link detected: yes
```

**

- I believe the problem is most likely caused by the broadcast arp
  requests coming from eth2 (standby) slave in the bond. Does anyone
  know how to turn off broadcast arp on a slave bond?

**

Comment: Are they managed switches? Do they support Link Aggregation?

Comment: Yes the switches are managed. The two eth ports eth2 and eth3 are not aggregated, they connect to separate switch for redundancy.

Comment: I have seen a lot of arp traffic on eth2 with is the standby nic in the bond, I'm thinking that the drops might be related to the broadcast arp requests.